# Apache incomplete downloads of large static file

Tags: apache-2.2

The file is a 40MB powerpoint file.

On my old server (RHEL 4, Apache 2.0, dedicated server), the file downloads without issue.

On my new server (Fedora 8, Apache 2.2, virtual server), I cannot get a complete download of the file using Firefox or IE.  wget is able to get a complete download (after making one or more 206 Partial Content requests).

Comparing the httpd.conf files from both servers, the only significant difference was that KeepAlive was On for the old server.  I changed KeepAlive to On for the new server, and that did not fix the issue.

I also tried turning off EnableSendfile and EnableMMAP on the new server, and that did not fix the issue.

What else should I try?

How can I determine if it is an apache issue, or caused by network issues with the new hosting company?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser caches, and also any proxy cache in front of you?  I had a similar problem once (incomplete download of a particular file) and it was just a local cache issue.

Comment: Try to download the file using FTP and SCP, also check what are the download rate and the latency between the client and the server and compare this results with your two providers. This could help you determine if the problem is with apache.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be the load balancer.  When I bypassed the load balancer, I was able to download the entire file.